# Absolute bottom positioning not working as expected in Edge and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have an icon that is absolute positioned at `bottom: 50px`, while this works fine in every browser, Edge and IE are the exceptions.  I understand there are a lot of problems with Microsoft's browsers and how they render differently. Here I see that the browser is treating the mid-way point of the `100vh` div as the bottom. What I need help with is to position the icon in IE & Edge the same way it is in Chrome, Opera and Firefox. Thanks.

### IE & Edge

[image]

### Chrome, Firefox, Opera

[image]

### HTML

```css
.content1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}


/* this is the icon I was talking about */

.dropdown_blue1 {
  width: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1"><img class="dropup_blue1" src="../assets/dropup_blue.png" alt=""><img class="dropdown_blue1" src="../assets/dropdown_blue.png" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this one, i have changed `margin: auto;` to `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
.content1 {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 99;
}
.dropdown_blue1 {
      width: 25px;
      padding: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      margin:0 auto; /* change here */
      z-index: 99;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
   <img class="dropdown_blue1" src="../assets/dropdown_blue.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! A better simpler solution!

Comment: I have the same issue , none of these solutions work

Comment: @NigelFds can you provide a link ?

Comment: Hi @JishnuVS its still in testing phase and the link is internal. But i changed the design so it doesnt need to be  position: absolute; . Thanks Anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the two browsers, position absolute was crazy. In style section I had.

```
td.Cir  {width:7in; height:7in; background-image:url('clock.png'); 
  background-size: 45%; background-position: center; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; position:relative; font-size:28pt;
  min-width:7in; max-width:7in; text-shadow: -1px 0 blue, 0 1px blue,
  1px 0 blue, 0 -1px blue;}
```

In a table I had

```
</td></tr><tr><td class='Cir'>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

I changed code to

```
<table><tr><td class='Cir'>...</td><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

and Edge and IE now work fine

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! Simply use `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` instead of `margin: auto;`